# Way to give many principals Invocation permissions to a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a lambda that will need access to more than 1 principal so I'm looking for ways to create all necessary invocation permissions in a CloudFormation template.

For example Accounts 123 and 456 will need access to MyFunction so something like this will **not** work:

```
Resources:
  LambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:${AWS::AccountId}:MyFunction
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction          
      Principal: "123,456"
```

...and it will not work because the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html) says that it only accepts string so I thought that maybe passing a *CommaDelimitedList* parameter to the CloudFormation template and using a Fn:Join could do the job. Something like this:

```
Parameters:
  MyAccounts:
    Description: All accounts
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
...
Resources:
  CrossInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Fn::Join:
        - ""
        - - '{"Principal": {"AWS": ["'
          - Fn::Join: ['","', {Ref: MyAccounts} ]
          - '"]}, "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction", "FunctionName" : "'
          - arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:${AWS::AccountId}:function:MyFunction
          - '"}'
```

My question is, is it possible to do what I'm trying? So far my efforts have failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is currently possible in single resource using only CloudFormation.

If you don't mind having multiple resources, you could have the InvokePermission block appear multiple times with different account IDs.  I'm assuming that isn't what you're looking for, though.

If you don't know in advance exactly how many accounts you'll need to allow access, or if you don't want that much repeated boilerplate, you can use a template preprocessor to generate the template from a smaller set of inputs.  The three top hits from google that look reasonable are [condense](https://github.com/wpalmer/condense), [fab_aws](https://github.com/dliggat/fab_aws), and [cloudformable](https://github.com/dliggat/cloudformable), but most devs I know have just written something on their own to fit their specific needs.